# Then follow something and something... - is this similar to "then come something and something"?

Tags: grammar

> The @param tag describes an argument accepted by the method. Each argument is listed in
>   the order expected by the method. Following @param is a keyword indicating the required
>   data type. In this case, all three arguments are expected to be integers (int). Then **follow** the name of the argument, and a brief description.

Is the word **follow** in this situation used in a similar fashion to how sometimes the word **come** is used when the subject(s) is placed right after it? Like, for example, ***"Now, comes a surprise"***. So, parsing that last sentence, we would have something like this: **follow** is the verb and **the name of the argument** and **a brief description** are the compound subjects. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep! You've got it exactly right.

Comment: The comma should be deleted in that sentence - it 'disjoins' the conjunct subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parsed this correctly: in the final sentence the verb and the ‘heavy’ conjunct subject are flipped so that the ‘lighter’ predicate is first and the ‘new information’ falls at the end of the sentence.